# How to re-generate titles for all entries in a section?

Tags: entries, tasks

Having changed the format of a Dynamic Entry Title, how do I get Craft to re-generate them all? I thought a background task would take care of it but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that dynamic titles only get updated whenever an entry is saved — so without using a plugin you would have to re-save them each manually. If you wanted to automate this process in a plugin, you would use something like this.

```
public function updateMySectionTitles()
{
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->section = 'mySection';
    $entries = craft()->elements->findElements($criteria);
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
    }
}
```

Untested (if anyone sees an error please comment). Also, keep in mind, this might only update the current locale — I'm not sure. You'll need to test, and modify if needed. You could also potentially add this is as a custom command to the [amcommand](https://github.com/am-impact/amcommand) plugin for easy access.